# Is it possible to have just opened apps on top in launcher? If so, how?

Tags: unity, launcher

I've locked ('pinned') quite some applications to the Unity launcher. When I open a programme (via the Dash), its icon appears at the very bottom of the list. This is very annoying IMHO as it leads to more mouse movements which require more precision (esp. annoying with a touchpad). 
Is there some way to make the icons of newly opened applications appear on top of the launcher?
[image: My current launcher, precision work!]

Answer (score 0):

No, however, folders may be an excellent option for you: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/add-stacks-to-unity-launcher-with.html