# Launched applications intrude into list of "locked" apps in Unity Launcher -- how to get to bottom?

Tags: unity, launcher

I've been using a fairly "vanilla" Ubuntu LTS setup since 14.04, and upgraded to 16.04 LTS a while back. It was painless, and everything seemed to be working normally. But I've recently noticed an oddity:

I use the "Super-[hold]" numbers for the locked apps as keyboard shortcuts. When other applications are launched, the have (up until recently) appeared at the bottom of the Launch sidebar, so the shortcut numbers remain constant.

Recently (when? not sure!) this behaviour has changed. Now, every time I start a non-locked application, it comes in at position #4, and the "unlocked" stack continues there, with other non-locked apps showing up under the "new" #4. Of course, this throws the previously stable <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>[0-9]</kbd> shortcut out of kilter.

To illustrate:

[image: screenshot of problem]

I have checked the Unity Tweak Tool for a setting for this, but found nothing relevant. I have also looked at the dconf-Editor under `com > canonical > unity > launcher`, but I'm none the wiser.

**Question**: How do I get the unlocked, launched apps to be added at the **bottom** of the Unity Launch sidebar (which used to be "normal"!)?

---

Possibly related, but no help:

- [Is it possible to have just opened apps on top in launcher? If so, how?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294428/is-it-possible-to-have-just-opened-apps-on-top-in-launcher-if-so-how)
- [How to make active application float to the top of the launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/755608/how-to-make-active-application-float-to-the-top-of-the-launcher)